'Objectives' button does not work often in NBA Live Mobile
The device is Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra. Is it only me who experienced this? The third tab 'Achievements' works very well, but the fourth tab 'Objectives' works occasionally, but does not work most of the time.. It is very annoying.. Of course, I have tried most of the common advices.. updated the OS and the game app. rebooted the device... deleted the cache.. tried everything I can do, but nothing has changed.
I guessed the touch screen might have the problem, so I rotated the screen but the it was the same, but it was the same.. so the screen is the the cause of the problem.
Edit: It might be a device model specific problem. I installed the same game to my Galaxy S23 Ultra device and the problem does not happen.

What do you mean exactly when you say it doesn’t always work? Does it just not go to that tab?

@Daemons I touch the button, and nothing happens as if I do nothing..
